# SQL select statement to sum totals of several cases and return percentage?

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I have a table for employees evaluations records which is related to another table that holds the evaluations subjects, it has 3 types of evaluations like:

1. Negative & Positive (represented as integer value in table "-3, -2" respectively).
2. No & Yes (represented as integer value in table "-1, 0" respectively).
3. value from 1 to 5 (represented as integer with same value).

So this is an example of the table design:

```
--------------------
| evaID      | int |
--------------------
| employeeID | int |
--------------------
| evaRec     | int |
--------------------
```

and this is example of the table data:

```
-------------------------------
| evaID | employeeID | evaRec |
-------------------------------
| 1     | 00001      | -3     |
-------------------------------
| 17    | 00001      | -2     |
-------------------------------
| 19    | 00001      | -2     |
-------------------------------
| 19    | 00001      | -1     |
-------------------------------
| 16    | 00002      | 3      |
-------------------------------
| 16    | 00005      | 0      |
-------------------------------
```

Now what I want is to select the sum of all records for specific employee as a percentage of the evaluations according to types but with separation of the 3 types like for ex *(not related to that table data)*:

- Negative and Positive type: 20% / 80%
- No & Yes type: 30% / 70%
- 1,2,3,4 or 5 type: 10% / 50% / 5% / 15% / 20%

So basically I want the select statement to return 6 float values represents the percentage of all the previous mentioned types as (floatNegative, floatNo, float1, float2 float3 and float4) and if possible - *but I know it's hard because I can't figure out the logic behind it yet* - I want it to return a 7th float value represents a percentage for all like bad vs good evaluation but I can't figure out yet how to mix the "Yes or No" which is 2 factor percentage, with the "1,2,3,4 or 5" which is 5 factors percentage!

So later in my c# code I will use the select results like:

- floatNegative = 20 (Negative = 20% and Positive = 100-floatNegative = 80%)
- floattNo = 30 (No = 30% and Yes= 100-floatNo = 70%)
- and so on with the 5 other numbers...

That means I have 3 separate groups of percentages calculations according to evaluation types mentioned above.

So finally if I run the query over employee "00001" from table above I'd get the resutls:

- floatNegative = 33.3
- floatPositive = 66.6
- floatNo = 100.0

because he has 1 x **"negative" record (-3)** and 2 x **"positive" records (-2)** with a total of 3 records. (*on "Negative/Positive" type group of evaluation*), and also he has 1 x **"no" record (-1)** but hasn't any **"yes" records (0)** that's why the result is 100% for "No" (*on "No/Yes" type group of evaluation*). and I don't care for other types results if he hasn't any records for it (like 1,2,3,4,5) it could be negative float value so I can distinguish it on my c# code to figure out that he has no records yet on this types and hide the percentage indicator text on my asp.net final markup.

Comment: Desired results would really help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff edited the question, please read again and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that you are looking for *conditional aggregation*. The logic is to `GROUP BY employeeID`, and then use various `SUM(CASE ...)` epressions to compute the intermediate sums.

Say you want to count *negative* evaluation of an employee, theu n :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec = -2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

You also compute the total positive and negative feedbacks :

```
SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (-2, -3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

Here is a full query using that principles. For binaries evaluation type (Positive/Negative, Yes/No), only one of the two values is computed (the other is just `1 - <this_value>`). For 1/2/3/4/5 types, each proportion is computed individualy.

```
SELECT
    employeeID,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec = -2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (-2, -3) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentPositive,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (-1, 0)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentYes,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentValue1,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentValue2,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentValue3,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentValue4,
    1.0 * SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec =  5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) / NULLIF(SUM(CASE WHEN evaRec IN (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END), 0) PercentValue5
FROM t
GROUP BY employeeID
```

NB : special care need to be taken to avoid division by 0.

This **[DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=ab0bbc8076ee0d6f2c7b6ee49dd1e3ff)** with your sample data returns :

```
employeeID | PercentPositive | PercentYes     | PercentValue1  | PercentValue2  | PercentValue3  | PercentValue4  | PercentValue5 
---------: | :-------------- | :------------- | :------------- | :------------- | :------------- | :------------- | :-------------
         1 | 0.666666666666  | 0.000000000000 | null           | null           | null           | null           | null          
         2 | null            | null           | 0.000000000000 | 0.000000000000 | 1.000000000000 | 0.000000000000 | 0.000000000000
         5 | null            | 1.000000000000 | null           | null           | null           | null           | null
```

Comment: First of all thanks for the neat answer and your time/effort. I will mark this as an answer although it is not quit exactly what I wanted but I can tweak it to get my results the way I wanted in the question (I didn't want a DataTable style result, I wanted only direct floats outputs but this is easy to tweak after you solved the harder part) but it's complete,correct and very smart approach. Thanks again!